# How to copy file from master to minions on salt-stack?

Tags: saltstack

I want to copy a file from salt stack master server to minion servers. I found a script from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687886/copy-a-file-from-salt-master-to-minions. But I got an error.

```
copy_my_files:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://srv/salt/nginx.conf
    - target: /etc/nginx
    - makedirs: True
```

Error:-

```
  ID: copy_my_files
    Function: file.recurse
      Result: False
     Comment: Specified file copy_my_files is not an absolute path
     Started: 09:46:24.850682
    Duration: 1.473 ms
     Changes:
```

I have given correct paths for both.

Comment: Hey Janith - I see you have asked a bunch of questions about saltstack - perhaps you should spend some time with the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file.recurse is for copying the content of a directory if I'm correct.
Here, what you have to do to copy just one file would be to use [file.managed](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed).

For instance reusing your example, this should be working:

```
copy_my_files:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - source: salt://nginx.conf
    - makedirs: True
```

Note that the nginx.conf file you want to copy has to be located in /srv/salt on the salt master. Thats the default place were the salt:// is pointing (unless you modified your configuration)

If you want to copy multiple file using the [file.recurse](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.recurse) it's also quite easy

```
deploy linter configuration:
  file.recurse:
    - name: "/usr/local/linter"
    - source: salt://devtools/files/linter
    - makedirs: True
    - replace: True
    - clean: True
```

Answer (score 4):

To simply copy a file, not as part of a state, use [`salt-cp`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/cli/salt-cp.html).

The source can be any file on the master. It does not need to be within the salt fileserver.

```
salt-cp '*' SOURCE [SOURCE2 SOURCE3 ...] DEST
```

Comment: And for multiple hosts just use the -L option such as -L host1,host2,...

Comment: @DavidRamirez the command already targets all minions. Use whatever targeting mechanism you like if that’s not what you want.

Comment: This is a good answer for a quick ad hoc command. I'd just like to provide an example (copy file to all Windows minions, targeting by grain): `salt-cp -G 'os:windows' script_in_salt_base_on_SaltMstr.ps1 'C:\My_scripts'`