# Can we write a chef cookbook to enable epel repository on centos

Tags: nginx, chef, cookbook

I have configured 3 centos servers for chefworkstation, chefserver and chefclient. Now I want to install nginx using the cookbook. For that I have below script.

```
package 'nginx' do
  action :install
end
```

This did not work because there were not enabled epel-release. Is there a way to enable epel repository before running above script?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/946639/how-to-copy-file-from-master-to-minions-on-salt-stack#comment1230007_946639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, but other people have done it before you so you can use their code.

From a simple google search I found the following official cookbook in Chef Supermarket:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/yum-epel#readme

Answer (score 1):

Definitely using the [yum-epel official cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/yum-epel) is a better solution, but for anyone who is looking for a fast fix, just install `epel-release` package:

```
package 'epel-release'
package 'nginx'
```